# How was this simplification achieved?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9809162) article, in Eq. (14), we are faced with the equation
$$e^{i\theta}=-\frac{e^{i(k_1+k_2)}+1-2e^{ik_1}}{e^{i(k_1+k_2)}+1-2e^{ik_2}},$$
where $\theta$ is real, while $k_1,k_2$ are complex. They claim that equivalently,
$$2\cot{\theta/2}=\cot{k_1/2}-\cot{k_2/2}.$$
How was this achieved? I have taken a course on complex analysis, but I don't see how we achieve one form from the other. I tried giving this to Mathematica, and it didn't simplify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $$e^{i\theta}=-\frac{e^{i(k_1+k_2)}+1-2e^{ik_1}}{e^{i(k_1+k_2)}+1-2e^{ik_2}}$$ is equivalent to $$\frac{e^{i\theta}+1}{e^{i\theta}-1}=\frac{e^{ik_2}-e^{ik_1}}{(e^{ik_1}-1)(e^{ik_2}-1)}$$

Now $$2\frac{e^{ik_2}-e^{ik_1}}{(e^{ik_1}-1)(e^{ik_2}-1)}=\frac{e^{ik_1}+1}{e^{ik_1}-1}-\frac{e^{ik_2}+1}{e^{ik_2}-1}$$

and $$i\frac{e^{i\theta}+1}{e^{i\theta}-1}=\cot \theta/2$$ and the same for $k_1,k_2$ gives the result

Comment: Nice answer, thanks for your help!

Comment: happy to be of help

Answer (score 4):

Let $$a = e^{i k_1}, \quad b = e^{i k_2}, \quad c = e^{i\theta}. \tag{1}$$  Then the given equation becomes
$$c = -\frac{ab + 1 - 2a}{ab + 1 - 2b}. \tag{2}$$
Then $$c-1 = -\frac{(ab + 1 - 2a) + (ab + 1 - 2b)}{ab + 1 - 2b} = -\frac{2(ab - a - b + 1)}{ab + 1 - 2b} = -\frac{2(a-1)(b-1)}{ab + 1 - 2b}, \tag{3}$$
and similarly
$$c+1 = -\frac{(ab + 1 - 2a) - (ab + 1 - 2b)}{ab + 1 - 2b} = \frac{2(a-b)}{ab + 1 - 2b}. \tag{4}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\frac{c+1}{c-1} &= - \frac{a-b}{(a-1)(b-1)} \\
&= - \frac{(a-1)-(b-1)}{(a-1)(b-1)} \\
&= \frac{1}{a-1} - \frac{1}{b-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{2}{a-1} - 1 - \frac{2}{b-1}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{a+1}{a-1} - \frac{b+1}{b-1} \right).
\tag{5}\end{align}$$

Now observe

$$\cot z = \frac{\cos z}{\sin z} = i \frac{e^{i z} + e^{-i z}}{e^{i z} - e^{-i z}} = i \frac{e^{2iz} + 1}{e^{2iz} - 1}, \tag{6}$$
so that
$$\cot \frac{z}{2} = i \frac{e^{iz} + 1}{e^{iz} - 1}. \tag{7}$$

So $(5)$ is equivalent to
$$2 \cot \frac{\theta}{2} = \cot \frac{k_1}{2} - \cot \frac{k_2}{2}. \tag{8}$$